# Bit-wise operation change the value?

Tags: c, loops, bit-manipulation

In this loop,:

```
for( i = 0; i < N>>1; i++)
```

does the N value shift throughout every repetition? i.e. if N=1024, then the first loop does

```
for( i = 0; i < 512; i++)
```

and the next loop does

```
for( i = 0; i < 256; i++)
```

Comment: There could be a language where this was the case. INTERCAL 2.0?

Comment: if you change it to N>>=1 then N will shift itself

Comment: Be careful if you use `N>>=1` in the test.  You need to understand the precedence rules of the operators.  `>>` has higher precedence than `<`, but `>>=` has lower precedence.  In either case some parentheses would be a good idea.

Comment: how can it change when you didn't assign new values to N anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not.  If you want to do that, then a construct like the following would do that:

```
for( i = 0; i < N; N >>= 1, i++)
```

Or put the shift inside of your loop.  The shift operator by itself doesn't change the value of the operand without an assignment statement.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're shifting the value of`N`, but you aren't assigning it a new value, so it doesn't change. Every iteration would be equivalent to this:

```
for( i = 0; i < 512; i++)
```